# Is there a way to persist data in my Blazor Server application from within the Startup.cs file itself?

Tags: c#, blazor, persistence, blazor-server-side

I am working on a Blazor Server application in which I need to persist a `String` created within the Startup.cs file itself, until the application is fully loaded; at which point I will retrieve that `String` and insert it into a database.

I ask this because Startup.cs is the place used to add services (database connectivity, sessions, etc.) to your Blazor application, and I can't seem to figure out a way.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Make a class set a property to the string. Then add that class to the service container. Later in a service inject the class.

Comment: @BrianParker The string gets generated within Startup.cs as soon as Startup.cs loads; I can't wait for another class to load first. Or, am I completely confused as to what you are suggesting? I am still fairly "new" to Blazor.

Answer (score 0):

```
SomeConfiguration myConfig = new() { Value = "some Value" };
services.AddSingleton(myConfig);
```

```
public class SomeConfiguration
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

You can now inject the class and retrieve its value anywhere you can use injection.

In a component using `@inject` or `[Inject]` or via the constructor of another service.

Comment: So, I followed this. But in order to access the `Value` outside of Startup.cs I need to do this: `services.AddScoped<SomeConfiguration>();` correct? I tried this but when I injected `SomeConfiguration` into my class, the `Value` was `null`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Brian `builder.Services.AddSingleton(myConfig);` uses the instance created with the value. What you did will create a new instance.

Comment: Is your builder variable `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder` ?

Comment: @Brian use `services` instead of `builder.Services`